# What happens to deleted data in linked list through this method?

Tags: c++, list

Lets imagine I have this filled linked list with various data numbers.

```
struct data{

    int num;
    data* next;

}* dataPointer;


dataPointer head = NULL;
dataPointer current = NULL;
dataPointer temp = NULL;
```

Adding new data nodes through this method

```
dataPointer newData() {

    dataPointer newData = new data;
    cout << "Data desired to add: ";
    cin >> newData->num;

    return newData;

}

void addData(dataPointer dataToAdd) {

    dataToAdd->next = NULL;

    if (head != NULL) {

        current = head;

        while (current->next != NULL)
            current = current->next;

        current->next = dataToAdd;

    }
    else
        head = dataToAdd;

}
```

And use this method to remove a node considering the data the user wants to remove

```
void deleteData(int dataToDelete) {

    if (head->num != dataToDelete){
        current = head;
        temp = head;

        while (current != NULL && current->num != dataToDelete) {

            temp = current;
            current = current->next;

        }

        if (current == NULL) {
            cout << "\n\t> Node with " << dataToDelete << " wasn't found in the stored data!\n" << endl;
            return;
        }else {

            current = current->next;
            temp->next = current;

        }
    }
    else
        head = head->next;

    cout << "\n\t> Node with " << dataToDelete << " was removed successfully!\n" << endl;

}
```

Obviously, it works and removes the desired data, but what happens to the data that I lost the address of? Does it get deleted by the IDE?
How should I proceed to avoid amounting garbage in the memory, if so happens?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing how the list is built but if you used `new` at all then there should be a call to `delete`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I just came up with this example. I'll make a function to show how I am adding new elements.

Comment: Anything you allocate with `new` should eventually be freed with `delete`, otherwise you leak memory.

Comment: @NathanOliver I changed up the code, can you check it up, please?

Comment: I think you have your answer by now ,,

Comment: @inkSession Reread Barmar's and mine comments.

Comment: I had tried to use delete, but I ended up with NullPointerExceptions in some instances, but I've managed to sort the problem. Thank you for the replies!

Answer (score 0):

When you delete it via your method, all you do is lose the address forever. Physically, that memory is not deleted.

Ultimately, when the program will quit, OS will usually free that memory (in fact, all the memory that was give to you will be taken back). The IDE does not delete it.

To avoid amounting garbage in the memory, you should deallocate the memory. Since you have used dynamic memory allocation to your data, you can use delete operator (or free function) to free the memory.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'm currently deleting correctly the data desired instead of just losing its address. I used the `delete` operator. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to make a call to `delete` when you find the data you intend to remove.

General rule: If you call `new` to allocate memory, you call `delete` to free it back up.